# How can I randomly select a question from an external file using python

Tags: python

I want to include questions in an external file using python. Then be able to randomly select a question and let the user enter in the answer, then select another random question? Also with a point system when answer is answered correctly. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Some missing info here:
- What's the size of the file?
- What does the structure look like?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you could provide some details such as what you've tried and the file size and structure, it will be much easier to assist you

Comment: You should probably look into JSON format and the `json` module for reading such files. Then get started. Then come back when you have an actual question.

Comment: You must parse your file depending on it's structure, and your file should be structured in some way. You can use existing parsers like `json` (if your questions stored as json) or write your own, if your file is `.txt`

Comment: This question has no [tag:python] in it. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @qasimzee just a small file with five questions, thanks

Comment: @qasimzee just a small file with 5 questions, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your file (`questions.txt`) has the format:

```
Question1
Question2
Question3
```

you could use:

```
import random
f = open("questions.txt", "r")
data = f.readlines()
f.close()
question = random.choice(data).rstrip()
print(question)
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. How would you add a point system, e.g 1 point for every correct answer